# How to identify the executable path of an installed application using powershell?

Tags: .net, powershell, batch-file, windows-installer, powershell-3.0

I install multiple applications (.msi) on different servers, am looking for a solution to identify the installed path of an application.

In powershell i used get-wmiobject to get the installed date and stuff but there is a installlocation property which returns blank. Is there any way of finding the executable location ? If not powershell any other tech will do.

Comment: In my opinion, registry infos for installed apps are better in the registry than in wmi. Have you tried to look in HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\<yourappli> ? (Or for 64 bits: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninst‌​all).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe https://psmsi.codeplex.com/ helps? It's a Windows Installer module for PowerShell. I haven't used it, but if you are interested in extracting info out of MSI files maybe it will help.